# I have a count data converted to proportion which test to use?

Tags: r, proportion

I am using R to build a model.
My outcome variable is the number of patients with specific disease of interest (Call it X) in health facilities over the past 7 days. I converted the count data to proportion by:
Number of patients with x in past 7 days/number of total patients past 7 daysX100 %.
I used Poisson regression but since there is overdispersion, I moved to Negative Binomial Poisson regression. One point I should mention is both the count data and the proportion are not normally distributed. I read that converting count data to percentages isn't advisable. But we want to appreciate the count of patients for the disease we are studying regarding the total number of patients visiting the facility for any illness. Is Negative binomial regression a best approach? do you suggest better approach?

Comment: Have you considered Binomial regression? It sounds very much as if you are modeling something binomial.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really make sense to me. Modelling a count of things (e.g. patients) as Poisson, Negative binomial or a version of these with overdispersion, and possibly with an offset for number of days or the like (these are, after all, distributions for counts - you could also truncate them, if you want to reflect that the total number of beds is limited). Modeling a percentage as Poisson (NegBin etc.) when you know the denominator makes no sense to me (your model doesn't even respect that a proportion needs to be in [0,1] / percentage in [0, 100]). If a known denominator, a percentage is better modelled as a binomial outcome (e.g. using a form of logistic regression) e.g. as X out of available bed-days (=number of beds times days). If you didn't know the denominator, something like beta-regression is an option.

Also, there's presumably some correlation (patients likely rarely stay one night, which you are not modeling, which you could try to do). It can often be a good idea to write down the data generating process and describe all of it using distributions that make sense.